# How come the same object may return different instanceof in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, animate-on-scroll

I am using the AOS plugin and it passes an object on custom event. The object looks like this:

```
[object Object]: {detail: Object}

detail: Object
accessKey: ""
align: ""

attributes: Object
baseURI: "http://localhost:3000/docs/countup.html"
childElementCount: 0

childNodes: Object

children: Object

classList: Object
className: "aos-init aos-animate"
clientHeight: 0
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 788
contentEditable: "inherit"

dataset: Object
dir: ""
draggable: false
firstChild: null
firstElementChild: null
hidden: false
hideFocus: false
id: ""
innerHTML: ""
innerText: ""
isContentEditable: false
lang: ""
lastChild: null
lastElementChild: null
localName: "h1"
msContentZoomFactor: 1
msRegionOverflow: "undefined"
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

nextElementSibling: Object

nextSibling: Object
nodeName: "H1"
nodeType: 1
nodeValue: null
offsetHeight: 0
offsetLeft: 32

offsetParent: Object
offsetTop: 48
offsetWidth: 788
onabort: null
onactivate: null
onbeforeactivate: null
onbeforecopy: null
onbeforecut: null
onbeforedeactivate: null
onbeforepaste: null
onblur: null
oncanplay: null
oncanplaythrough: null
onchange: null
onclick: null
oncontextmenu: null
oncopy: null
oncuechange: null
oncut: null
ondblclick: null
ondeactivate: null
ondrag: null
ondragend: null
ondragenter: null
ondragleave: null
ondragover: null
ondragstart: null
ondrop: null
ondurationchange: null
onemptied: null
onended: null
onerror: null
onfocus: null
ongotpointercapture: null
oninput: null
oninvalid: null
onkeydown: null
onkeypress: null
onkeyup: null
onload: null
onloadeddata: null
onloadedmetadata: null
onloadstart: null
onlostpointercapture: null
onmousedown: null
onmouseenter: null
onmouseleave: null
onmousemove: null
onmouseout: null
onmouseover: null
onmouseup: null
onmousewheel: null
onmscontentzoom: null
onmsgesturechange: null
onmsgesturedoubletap: null
onmsgestureend: null
onmsgesturehold: null
onmsgesturestart: null
onmsgesturetap: null
onmsinertiastart: null
onmsmanipulationstatechanged: null
onpaste: null
onpause: null
onplay: null
onplaying: null
onpointercancel: null
onpointerdown: null
onpointerenter: null
onpointerleave: null
onpointermove: null
onpointerout: null
onpointerover: null
onpointerup: null
onprogress: null
onratechange: null
onreset: null
onscroll: null
onseeked: null
onseeking: null
onselect: null
onselectstart: null
onstalled: null
onsubmit: null
onsuspend: null
ontimeupdate: null
onvolumechange: null
onwaiting: null
onwebkitfullscreenchange: null
onwebkitfullscreenerror: null
onwheel: null
outerHTML: "<h1 class="aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="" data-toggle="countup" data-to="256" data-from="0" data-aos-id="countup:in"></h1>"
outerText: ""

ownerDocument: Object

parentElement: Object

parentNode: Object
prefix: null

previousElementSibling: Object

previousSibling: Object
scrollHeight: 0
scrollLeft: 0
scrollTop: 0
scrollWidth: 788
spellcheck: true

style: Object
tabIndex: 0
tagName: "H1"
textContent: ""
title: ""

__proto__: Object

__proto__: Object
```

The object above is passed as `e.detail`. The problem is when I run `e.detail instanceof Element` it returns `true` in all browsers but IE and Edge. In IE and Edge it returns `false`, so I cannot work with it as a normal DOM Element. Any ideas why? Is there a way to parse it or something?

Comment: *"...so I cannot work with it as a normal DOM Element..."* Why not? There's no need to use `instanceof` on it in order to "work with it as a normal DOM Element."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, sorry, I should have mentioned that it's not only that `instanceof` returns `false`, it also doesn't *act* like a normal element. I cannot get its `classList`, `dataset`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on much when it comes to host-provided objects like DOM elements. As you've found, different hosts are free to implement things in different ways.

Separately: `instanceof` isn't reliable cross-[realm](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-code-realms). So if you're getting an object (of any kind, not just a host-provided object) from another window (which is another realm), `instanceof` will probably fail. That's because the way `instanceof` works is by checking the prototype chain of the object you all it on and seeing if any of its prototypes is the object on the `prototype` property of the function you're comparing it to (`Element`, in your example). That's part of why we have `Array.isArray`, because `a instanceof Array` fails if the array comes from another window.

There's no reason to use `instanceof` on a DOM element. Just use the element. If you want to make sure it's an element, a fairly reliable check is `a.detail.nodeType === 1`. (Reliable as in: It'll work for any DOM element. Naturally, if someone gives you an object with a `nodeType` property with the avlue 1 that isn't a DOM element, it'll pass the check, but...)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that it's not only that `instanceof` returns `false`, it also doesn't *act* like a normal element. I cannot get its `classList`, `dataset`, etc.

Comment: @sdvnksv - Please make all [mcve]s **on-site**, not off-site. In most cases, you can make it runnable using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). But even if not, it needs to be on-site (in your question). People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you, and off-site resources can disappear, making the question/answer unuseful to people in the future.